# Spark Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, hierarchy

I am interested in [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com), but i cant use it in trial mode.
I installed latest version. Then i used framework setup assistant, but it not helps.
Building settings are correct - i checked it step by step with this instructions: http://www.sparkinspector.com/framework_setup.html
I also tried to clean project and delete app from iOS simulator.
The app is for iPad, i don't know is it matter.

The error i getting is: "Setup did not complete successfully. The Spark Inspector timed out waiting for the console to settle."

Comment: I use Spark Inspector often with the simulator. Nothing needs to be changed in the app. Spark Inspector adds a "Inspect With Spark" menu item to the Product menu in Xcode, I just use that. The framework is only needed to use Spark Inspector with an app running on a device.

Answer (score 1):

I love this tool - It actually includes a wizard that lets you choose a xcode project and sets it up for inspection. try using the built in wizard.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: With version 1.3.3 of Spark Inspector, it seems it sometimes takes a while for SI to connect to the process.  After you get the error, try clicking the OK button and wait for about 30 seconds.  It should eventually connect.  Otherwise, try some of the other tips below.

Deleting the Xcode Derived Data sometimes fixes this for me:

1. launch Xcode
2. from menubar: Xcode > preferences
3. click the 'Locations' tab
4. beneath "Derived Data" you'll see a path with a small arrow icon, click on the arrow
5. from the Finder window that appears, drag the 'DerivedData' folder (should be automatically selected) into the trash
6. quit Xcode
7. restart Xcode and try launching Spark Inspector again

Another thing to check is to make sure your command line tools are setup to run the same version as your current version of Xcode (happens sometimes if you have multiple copies installed at the same time like a beta):

1. launch Xcode
2. from menubar: Xcode > preferences
3. click the 'Locations' tab
4. Check the current value for 'Command Line Tools'.  If it's not the same version as the Xcode version you're trying to run Spark from, then:

   1. Select correct version
   2. Delete the Derived Data
   3. Quit Xcode
   4. Restart Xcode
   5. Clean your project (cmd-K)
   6. Try re-running with Spark

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Make sure you have the dylib in the following path:
Applications/Spark Inspector.app/Contents/Resources/Frameworks/SparkInspector.dylib

I re-installed the application, force xcode to quit, re-opened xcode and the project. I've clean the project as you did and then use Product-Inspect with spark.

It takes few secondes to start after the simulator is launch. It also breaks on a line on the debugger until the inspector app is launched.

Hope this will help

Comment: My Product-Inspect with spark is never enabled, I have to run on device and run app, then select my app in Spark. Am I doing something different?